# How to get all days and date of selected month from CalendarExtender control in c#.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Can anyone please tell me how to get all days and date of selected month from calendar in .net.This is to create attendance of employees.

I need each days and date of the selected month to be displayed in label box.Like sun,mon,tue etc ...and 1,2,3....28 or 29 or 30 or 31  based on the month and year I selected.

Comment: why dont you just use asp.net calendar? e.g. <asp:Calender ID = "Calendar1" runat = "server">
</asp:Calender>

Comment: Do you want the values in java-script?

Comment: If I would get values in javascript,it also ok.